# Rake generate - not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, redmine

I am installing redmine1.4 and following [these step](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) .

I am in 5 step of **installation process**

When I am trying to do `rake generate_session_store` its saying to install rdoc 
Please let me know do I really need to create document cant I skip that **OR** 
if I need to create docs then **how to install rdoc** with proper version .

I am using :

```
    Rails 2.3.14
    RubyGems 1.8
    ruby 1.8.7
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error message, it's just a naggy warning - your task has probably completed fine (as indicated by the updating of `session_store.rb` in `config/initializers`.

This does btw not look like a programming question to me, why not ask on the [Redmine forums](http://www.redmine.org)?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a warning message and you can skip it. Even though you can remove this rdoc message disappear

If you have redmine's trunk version, edit Gemfile and add the following line:

```
 gem "rdoc", ">= 2.4.2
```

Then run bundle install